# is there a straightforward way to turn off an integer bit in java?

Tags: java, int, bit

im trying to simplify my database by saving boolean data in numeric fields, right now im doing this to turn on and off a bit.

```
int turnBit(int input, int bit, boolean value){
    if(value){
        input = input | (1<<bit);
    }else{
        input = input | (1<<bit);
        input = input ^ (1<<bit);
    }
    return input;
}
```

is there any way to turn off the bit without turning it on before?

Comment: This might simplify your database schema by reducing the number of fields, but the downside is that querying the bit fields becomes more difficult and harder to for the query optimizer to optimize.

Comment: This new field only holds some user parametrization, so there is no need for querying. Since im using mysql, using a single integer instead of tinyInt to save individual parameters would help me save some hard drive space and broadband, I assume.

Comment: There is no need for querying ... until there is :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the bitwise 'or' operator to turn on a bit, and this is correct:

```
0001 | 0010 results in 0011
```

You can use the bitwise 'and' function to turn off a bit:

```
1101 & 1110 results in 1100
```

So to turn off one bit of a value, you make a 'bit mask' which has all the bits you do NOT care about set to 1, and the one that you want to turn off set to 0; that will 'turn off' that bit in the value.

If you have a mask for turning on a particular bit -- that is, one with 0 in each position you don't want to change and a 1 in the position you do want to change, you can transform it into the "turn off" bit mask by applying java's bitwise 'not' operator (~), i.e., ~0010 results in 1101.

Answer (score 3):

```
input = input & ~(1 << bit)
```